# Failure to install popper (failure in a git command)

Tags: git, npm, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I am trying to install popper (as it is a peer dependency to bootstrap). But in doing so, I am getting the error "Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url".

I already tried the 'git config --system core.longpaths true' command, but I am still getting the same error.

Full error message:

```
> npm ls
volvo-style@1.0.0 E:\Webapps\AspCore\Vcg.AspCore.Template\content\src\__VcgTemplateName__.Web
+-- bootstrap@4.0.0
+-- jquery@3.3.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.12.9

npm ERR! peer dep missing: popper.js@^1.12.9, required by bootstrap@4.0.0

SDECLE12@GNL10075NMJC2 E:\Webapps\AspCore\Vcg.AspCore.Template\content\src\__VcgTemplateName__.Web
> npm i --save popper
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  pemrouz/buble resetting remote C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-e606a5a1 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-e606a5a1: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-e606a5a1'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-e606a5a1: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-e606a5a1: github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=No error
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-e606a5a1: github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No error
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git) fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pemrouz/buble.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  pemrouz/buble resetting remote C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a:

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a: and the repository exists.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\rijs.resdir\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "--save" "popper"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:pemrouz/buble.git C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\sdecle12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-pemrouz-buble-git-ee085e1a'...
npm ERR! ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Webapps\AspCore\Vcg.AspCore.Template\content\src\__VcgTemplateName__.Web\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the mistake was the **name** of the package I needed to install.

I did:

```
npm i --save popper
```

But should have done:

```
npm i --save popper.js
```

Comment: I checked it and I think there is error in documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper. First I used "npm i popper" but it wasn't working so I changed to "npm i popper.js" and it works. Thanks for advice!

Comment: It's **not** an error in the docs: there is actually a package called "popper", and it's not the one you need for bootstrap. Bootstrap requires popper.js. Here's the link to its npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js